# Skewed capactior on a motherboard

Tags: capacitor, soldering, motherboard

I've bought a new motherboard, and after unpacking I realized that one of the capacitors is a bit skewed:

[image]
[image]

Can it cause any problems? Should I request RMA?

Comment: it seems all normal to me...how it's skewed from your point of view?

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Nothing serious, maybe 5 degrees. I feel silly :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not big deal.  Nothing wrong here.  All withing normal.  Get over it.